# I get an error message in example of pag. 81 of Manual for version 3.0.1a of TikZ and PGF Packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I have copied the following code and have reconstructed the lost line breaks in the copy-paste.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \begin{scope}[
        every node/.style={concept,circular drop shadow,execute at begin node=\hskip0pt},
        root concept/.append style={
            concept color=black,fill=white,line width=1ex,text=black,font=\large\scshape},
        text=white,
        computational problems/.style={concept color=red,faded/.style={concept color=red!50}},
        computational models/.style={concept color=blue,faded/.style={concept color=blue!50}},
        measuring complexity/.style={concept color=orange,faded/.style={concept color=orange!50}},
        solving problems/.style={concept color=green!50!black,faded/.style={concept color=green!50!black!50}},
        grow cyclic,
        level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm,sibling angle=90,font=\scshape},
        level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45,font=\scriptsize}]
        \node[root concept] {  ComputationalComplexity}% root
        child[computational problems] {node{ComputationalProblems}
            child{node{ProblemMeasures} }
            child{node{ProblemAspects} }
            child[faded] {node{ProblemDomains} }
            child{node{KeyProblems} }}
        child[computational models] {node{ComputationalModels}
            child{node{TuringMachines} }
            child[faded] {node{Random-AccessMachines} }
            ...
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, the Latex editor returns the following error:

[image]

Comment: There has to be a semicolon in the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You copied a fragment. You need to, at least, make sure you keep all the closing braces and semicolon. Also, if you post examples, make sure that they start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}` so that they can be at least in principle be compiled.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap]
    \begin{scope}[
        every node/.style={concept,circular drop shadow,execute at begin node=\hskip0pt},
        root concept/.append style={
            concept color=black,fill=white,line width=1ex,text=black,font=\large\scshape},
        text=white,
        computational problems/.style={concept color=red,faded/.style={concept color=red!50}},
        computational models/.style={concept color=blue,faded/.style={concept color=blue!50}},
        measuring complexity/.style={concept color=orange,faded/.style={concept color=orange!50}},
        solving problems/.style={concept color=green!50!black,faded/.style={concept color=green!50!black!50}},
        grow cyclic,
        level 1/.append style={level distance=4.5cm,sibling angle=90,font=\scshape},
        level 2/.append style={level distance=3cm,sibling angle=45,font=\scriptsize}]
        \node[root concept] {  ComputationalComplexity}% root
        child[computational problems] {node{ComputationalProblems}
            child{node{ProblemMeasures} }
            child{node{ProblemAspects} }
            child[faded] {node{ProblemDomains} }
            child{node{KeyProblems} }}
        child[computational models] {node{ComputationalModels}
            child{node{TuringMachines} }
            child[faded] {node{Random-AccessMachines} }};
%            ...
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, user238301!. I hadn't realized that it was just a fragment that I was copying. When it comes to closing parentheses, braces, or square brackets, as well as semicolons, it is not always easy to detect mismatches or omissions.

Of course, I have carried out the test within the begin {document} environment, and having loaded the necessary packages in the preamble.